# Mac OSX | Choose custom "Open with >" programs

Tags: macos, file-types

I open a lot of text files in different programs and it's REALLY annoying selecting "Other" and then selecting "All applications" from "Recommended applications" every single time it's not the default one.

[image]

Comment: I want to add 3 different programs to the list, one being Excel

Comment: Needs more info - at lest, what file type? What OS? I get a choice of 16 different apps to open a .txt file, including Excel. Possibly needs the Launch Services database rebuilding. Try [Onyx](http://www.titanium.free.fr) Maintenance/Rebuilding

Comment: Um there's a few different file types. For example, .txt or .csv I want to be able to open easily in text edit and excel.  I have some other 3rd party programs that would useful for opening biology format files like .gbk where I'd like to be able to open in text edit as well. I'm running Yosemite